# Twitter API error when asking for place trend

Tags: python, api, twitter

I'm trying to create a twitter trending app using a code that I found on O'Reilly but when I run this:

```
import tweepy 
import credentials
import twitter
auth  = tweepy.OAuthHandler(credentials.API_KEY, credentials.API_SECRET_KEY)
auth.set_access_token(credentials.ACCESS_TOEKN, credentials.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
gr_id=23424833
woe_id=1
world_trends=api.trends_place(_id=woe_id)
```

I get the following error: 
`TweepError: [{'code': 34, 'message': 'Sorry, that page does not exist.'}]`

Does anyone know how to solve that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `woe_id` and how old is the code you're trying to run?

Comment: Hello Andy and thanks for your answer. The woe_id is the where on earth ID. I'm using the O'Reilly book Mining the Social Web, December 2018 edition.

Comment: what is the variable `woe_id` set to when it is passed to this function?

Comment: woe_id=1 in this example, but I tried it with various different ids and it was giving me the same error.

Comment: Can you expand your code - is this using the python-twitter library? Twython? Tweepy?

Comment: I just edited the question with the whole code.